# Best practice for panning/zooming a user control?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, telerik, zooming, deepzoom

We currently have a user control which displays a dynamic matrix of other user controls.  Since it's dynamic, the view can become large, requiring the user to scroll up/down & left/right in the browser to view everything.

I would like to give the users one view of the user control with the ability to pan & zoom on it, much like the feel of [this](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#Map/FirstLook) Telerik control.  We own the Telerik controls and I've tried to use the Map control for our purpose, but it doesn't seem like that is going to be a good solution.

I have also placed a Canvas inside of a scroll viewer, and was able to make it pan (using scroll bars) & zoom (using Scale Tranform).  This works pretty well, but it's not smooth like the Telerik control is.

So, I'm wondering what other ways there are to do this.  Am I overlooking a Silverlight control that would work for me?  Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not smooth like the Telerix control is"?  I've used this exact solution in the past and found it to be very fast and very smooth.

Comment: When I zoom in, it just snaps to the next zoom level.  I suppose i could do some type of transition animation to make it feel smoother.  Also, they have the ability to 'throw' when panning.  I'm not exactly sure how to do that.  Any suggestions?  I'm glad to hear that you approached it the same way I did, I must be on the right track!

Comment: I forgot to mention one thing that I was unable to implement.  I wanted the users to be able to zoom to the location of the mouse.  My current implementation would just straight in on the object.  I'm sure I could get this to work, I was just curious if there's a control out there that already does this, and didn't want to make this harder than it needs to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this](http://zoomcontrol.codeplex.com/) on CodePlex and I like their approach.  I will probably be customizing it to be exactly what I want, but it's a good start.  Note: It does not implement the 'throwing' capabilities.