# Magnify pan and zoom Image in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight-3.0, silverlight-4.0, zooming

How can i implement zoom , Pan , Magnify in silverlight.
I have big image so my image is inside scroll viewer.

and after zooming and panning i need to save position and zoom setting in database so when user back to screen can see same image area.

Answer (score 1):

I have used [this](http://zoomcontrol.codeplex.com/) CodePlex ZoomControl before, which worked great for us.  We didn't save the position, but I think it would be possible to save and load the MatrixTransform that this control uses.  There's an example of how to implement this control on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131137/scroll-image-by-dragging-the-mouse/3187782#3187782) previous question that I answered.  I know I didn't directly answer your question, but maybe this will help you get to a working solution.