# Zoom control to SilverLight Form

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, zooming

I still have not found the answer: How can I implement a zoom control to my  SilverLight Form?
I hope you will help me with this question)  I am looking to zoom the controls inside the zoom control, not zoom on an image.

Comment: I added a new answer with a different type of zooming.  Maybe that will better meet your need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/zoomandpancontrol.aspx) is a WPF control that zooms the child controls.  Should be fairly easy to convert to Silverlight.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2929472/best-practice-for-panning-zooming-a-user-control) is a silverlight control that does the same thing:

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7472741/zoom-control-to-silverlight-form) `It is nor very easy to convert source code to Silverlight, because a great number of WFP classes don't exist in Silverlight`. @mydogisbox

Comment: I added a link to a silverlight control that does the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/ZoomAndPan.aspx

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7472741/zoom-control-to-silverlight-form)  **bold** `Very good information. but that's not that I wanted to find. I need not enlarge the static picture but the elements of Grid, dynamically changing`.@mydogisbox

Comment: I added an answer for your clarified question, but I'm going to leave this answer as well since it is closely related.

Answer (score 1):

With ScaleTransform in RenderTransform

```
<Grid.RenderTransform>
    <TransformGroup>
        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1"/>
    </TransformGroup>
</Grid.RenderTransform>
```

http://ganshani.com/2009/08/14/zoom-in-and-out-in-silverlight/

Edit:  the other link doesn't work.  Here is the [internet archive version](http://web.archive.org/web/20100211100932/http://www.ganshani.com/2009/08/14/zoom-in-and-out-in-silverlight/).